# Responsive - All elements are way too small on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive, meta-tags

I am working on a website right know, but I have a weird issue with the view on mobile devices. 
When I resize the window on a desktop browser the elements and fonts are changing with the viewport how they should.
When I open the website on a mobile device all fonts and elements (e.g. the burger menu) are way to small. It looks like it is a scaling issue or something similar. 
I have the meta viewport tag in the head so that is not the issue.

I couldn't find any similar questions here or on any other forum. I hope somebody can help.
I have attached some screenshots, but if necessary I can provide the URL.
Thank you in advance.

[Full Screen Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLy79.jpg)
[Resized Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzgvw.png)
[Responsive example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tilv8.png)
[Resposive example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibKBL.png)

Comment: provide the URL plz

Comment: Are you using either percentages or em to set your font size?

Comment: @josh I used em to set the font size

Comment: An interesting thing about using `em` as a unit of measurement is that it's relative to the parent element. So, if you have several nested HTML elements (div, span, etc.) that are all using `em`, they're each basing their font size on their parent element, and that can lead to some unpredictable outcomes that only manifest in mobile layout. You might instead try using `rem` as a unit of measurement, since it's always relative to the root font-size of `html`.

Comment: I'll try it, but that doesn't explain why the burger menu has the wrong size as well.. here is the url: clmsftsw.com

Answer (score 11):

Make sure to include responsive meta tag to insure that your browser gets the right width of your device instead of zooming out the page

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
> ```
>
> This means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the
>   page at the width of its own screen. So if that screen is 320px wide,
>   the browser window will be 320px wide, rather than way zoomed out and
>   showing 960px (or whatever that device does by default, in lieu of a
>   responsive meta tag).

Further reading **[Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)**

Comment: I have the meta tag included like I said in the original post. That is not the issue.

Comment: so please provide a code/link/fiddle anything that could refer to the problem

Comment: The link to the website is: clmsftsw.com